# CakePHP Render diffent view in different Controller

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i create a Button in a View that start a javascript function that start a post request to a function in my controller. Now i want in this controller to say render a ctp file in the view from the button.

This is my start view named 'show_article':

```
<p>Add Article here</p>
<form>
<p>Articlename: <span id="ajax_name_text"></span></p> <input type="text" id="ajax_name">
 Preis: <input type="number" id="ajax_preis">
 Anzahl: <input type="number" id="ajax_anzahl">
 <button type="button" onClick="add_article_ajax()">Add Article</button>
 </form>
```

the button start a javascript function with this:

```
$.post('/users/addArticleAjax',{

    article_name: new_insert_name,
    preis: new_insert_preis,
    anzahl: new_insert_anzahl,
    owner: new_insert_owner

}, function(message){

    alert(message);

});
```

and in the users controller is the function 'addArticleAjax' with this:

```
$this->autoRender = false;

    $articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
    $article = $articlesTable->newEntity();

    $article->name = $this->request->data('article_name');
    $article->price = $this->request->data('preis');
    $article->anzahl = $this->request->data('anzahl');
    $article->owner = $this->request->data('owner');

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')){ 

        //$articlesTable->save($article);

        //insert ctp view in show_article

    }
```

i tried with this `$this->render('test_ajax_call');` but this send a response back to the javascript and this is not what i want.
i want to insert the ctp data over php in the start view

Comment: what your problem actually is ? are you having problem in inserting data from ajax ?

Comment: Any Ajax call is *always* going to send the response back to the JavaScript. It's up to your JavaScript to do what is necessary with it.

Comment: PHP can't update anything on the client. You have to do that with javascript.